# Highcharts Line rendering time takes too long

Tags: highcharts

I try to generate a line graph. 12 elements in Y and little over 1000 elements in X. It takes too long to render this chart. Boost option is not working.

[image]

Comment: Hi @gayan1991, I've tried to recreate the problem, but creating a chart with 12 series with 1000 points for each takes much less time than 40 seconds. Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rbc9kwae/ Could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?